# flutter path error PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Whenever I use the stagehand command, I must first export the command

```
PATH = "$ PATH": "$ HOME / Development / flutter / bin / cache / dart-sdk / bin"
```

If I close the terminal and run the stagehand command again, it will give an error again and I must run that command first.
What should I do if I no longer need the export above command?

Can the path file be edited manually? If yes, from where?

this error is for ubuntu linux.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26047/

Answer (score 0):

Every time the terminal starts, the environment variables will be reset. If you want to export your variable each time your terminal opens, just put the export command in a file which terminal reads each time it opens.

Like `.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` or if you use zsh `.zshrc`.